# How to return data in login function in PL/pgSQL? I want to return table where email and password matches. Email is unique

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

The function doesn't throw any error nor does it show any return value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION login(iemail VARCHAR,ipassword VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE(id INTEGER, name VARCHAR, lastName VARCHAR, age INTEGER, mobile VARCHAR,email VARCHAR)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $$
#variable_conflict use_variable
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY SELECT id, name, lastName, age, mobile,email from usertable WHERE email = iemail AND password = ipassword;
END;
$$;
```

Below query gives me a return value. So, I know my query statement is right. Also, return type of variables are also checked.

```
SELECT id, name, lastName, age, mobile,email from usertable 
WHERE email='jaysrdra@gmail.com' AND password ='passwords';
```

i am calling the function with:

```
SELECT * FROM login('jaysrdra@gmail.com','passwords');
```

Comment: How exactly are you calling the function?

Comment: I am also calling function with pg-promise library in api request. But that is also returning null array

Comment: Why is this tagged with MySQL if you search for a PostgreSQL solution? Also, what have you tried to resolve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#variable_conflict use_variable` is the reason. As all your output variables (=columns) have the same name as the table columns, Postgres returns the output "variables" which are not initialized.

Use an explicit table reference inside the function's query to avoid the name clash:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION login(iemail VARCHAR,ipassword VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE(id INTEGER, name VARCHAR, lastName VARCHAR, age INTEGER, mobile VARCHAR, email VARCHAR)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY 
    SELECT u.id, u.name, u.lastname, u.age, u.mobile, u.email 
    from usertable u
    WHERE u.email = iemail 
    AND u.password = ipassword;
END;
$$;
```

---

Note that for encapsulating a simple query into a function a `language sql` function is typically the better choice - it also avoids the clash between variables and column names:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION login(iemail VARCHAR,ipassword VARCHAR)
  RETURNS TABLE(id INTEGER, name VARCHAR, lastName VARCHAR, age INTEGER, mobile VARCHAR, email VARCHAR)
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
  SELECT id, name, lastname, age, mobile, email 
  from usertable 
  WHERE email = iemail 
  AND password = ipassword;
$$;
```

Comment: Thank you @horse_with_no_name. I used `#variable_conflict use_variable` to avoid   `ERROR:  column reference "name" is ambiguous`.  No errors after using it but that made it harder to debug.

Comment: Using an explicit table reference inside the function's query to avoid the name clash; solved everything.

Answer (score 0):

Looks more like you are not calling the function correctly , should be something like this to call it.

```
SELECT * INTO some_variable FROM login('jaysrdra@gmail.com', 'passwords');
```

Comment: The `into some_variable` is not needed (in fact it's wrong if you want to use the function in plain SQL)